# I got key for every item in the listView and its saved to Firebase I want to send that key to another activity but every time I got the same key

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-intent

```
      mChildEventListner = new ChildEventListener() {
          @Override
           public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
                AdClass adClass = dataSnapshot.getValue(AdClass.class);
              list.add(0,adClass);
               listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

- here I save the key in global variable named listId.

  ```
       listId = dataSnapshot.getKey();
       }

     -here I send that id via intent to another activity 
     AdsList.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
              Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(),AdsDescrption.class);
              intent.putExtra("resId",listId);
              startActivity(intent);
          }
        });
  ```

-and the problem I always get the same key

```
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        resId =intent.getStringExtra("resId");
```

Comment: if you put `AdsList` at the below `listId = dataSnapshot.getKey();` , what will happen

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                //Your code goes here

            }
        });
```

Comment: i try it too i got  same result and the first item from the list not clickable! i dont know why.